# What's the best way to seperate the first record in an array from all others using rails?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array (`@tasks`) from a database select and I want to display the first on its own and then loop through any others.

There will always be one item in the array but there may or may not be more than one.

What's the best way to show the first one and then loop through any remaining items, if there are any more?

I thought I found something similar on SO the other day but I can't seem to find it again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.9.3-p327 > a = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
1.9.3-p327 > first, *the_rest = *a
 => [1, 2, 3] 
1.9.3-p327 > first
 => 1 
1.9.3-p327 > the_rest
 => [2, 3]
```

However, in the above case, if `a = [1]` then `the_rest` will end up being `nil` (at least in ruby 1.9, dunno about 1.8)

You could also use `.shift` to remove the first element like so:

```
1.9.3-p327 > first = a.shift
 => 1 
1.9.3-p327 > first
 => 1 
1.9.3-p327 > a
 => [2, 3] 
1.9.3-p327 >
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply. The syntax for your first example looks a bit advanced for me and not quite as readable (at least to me). The second one made sense but didn't quite suit my view code.

Comment: I'm always looking to do things better. Are you able to point me in the direction of documentation about your first method so I can read up about it?

Comment: Google "ruby splat operator"... https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+splat+operator

Comment: After reading up about the splat operator I've now updated my code to use it so I've changed the chosen answer to be yours instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You can use this:

```
first = @tasks.first
```

Others:

```
others = @tasks[1..@tasks.length]
```

Display on view:

```
<%= @tasks.first %>
<% @tasks[1..@tasks.length].each do |task| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: This worked a treat, although I exchanged `@tasks[1..@tasks.length]` for `@tasks[1..-1]`. Thanks.

Comment: @user1116573 you are free to do what you feel comfortable, thanks for accept :)